# After successful social sign in, i get ‘Open with ’ option in custom tabs

Tags: android, auth0, auth0-lock, auth0-delegated-admin

I am using CustomTabsIntent to launch social sign in by using Auth0., but after successful sign, i get 2 options to launch the app.

This is what i get after successful sign in & sign up`

[image]

This is my code.

```
 final Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
        uriBuilder.scheme("https")
                .authority(getString(R.string.com_auth0_domain))
                .appendPath("authorize")
                .appendQueryParameter("code_challenge_method", "S256")
                .appendQueryParameter("code_challenge", codeChallenge)
                .appendQueryParameter("audience", getString(R.string.auth0_audience))
                .appendQueryParameter("scope", "openid profile offline_access email")
                .appendQueryParameter("client_id", getString(R.string.com_auth0_client_id))
                .appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", getString(R.string.auth0_callback))
                .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "code")
                .appendQueryParameter("prompt", "login")
                .appendQueryParameter("connection", connection);

        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                .addDefaultShareMenuItem()
                .setToolbarColor(this.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setShowTitle(true)
                .build();

        openUrlForResult(customTabsIntent, uriBuilder.build().toString(), 1001);`
```

I need to know why its showing 2 options to launch the same app,

Comment: You can try to get an answer on https://community.auth0.com/ maybe, it's the Auth0 community forum.